# Sentry Express error handling middleware doesn't work for me

Tags: node.js, sentry

I've tried this example from Sentry docs, but instead of catching the exception and reporting it to Sentry, the exception goes unhandled and I get a stack trace from the app's stderr and nothing is registered in Sentry.

The DSN is right (I can send events programmatically) and the option *filter out requests from localhost* is off.

```js
    import express from 'express';
    import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

    Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY_DSN });
    const webServer = express();
    webServer.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
    webServer.get('/forceError', (req) => {
      throw new Error('Exception thrown');
    });
    webServer.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
    webServer.listen(80, () => console.log('http on :80'));
```